# Why does Javascript function returns undefined after completion

Tags: javascript, function, return

That's the function:

```
function randomNum(n) {
  const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  if(numbers.includes(n)) {
    console.log('ok')
  } else {
    console.log('Choose a value between 1 and 10')
  }
}
console.log(randomNum(5))
```

Sorry if it's a simple problem, but i can't figure it out, i'm kinda new to programing. The function is returning 'undefined' after 'ok' or 'Choose a value between 1 and 10'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `console.log(<value>);`, try using a `return <value>;` statement.
At the moment, your code runs the function `randomNum`, prints the result to the console, then prints the return value from the function. Without an explicit `return` statement, this return value is `undefined`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything, it only logs. To fix add return.

```
function randomNum(n) {
    const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    if(numbers.includes(n)) {
      return 'ok';
    } else {
      return 'Choose a value between 1 and 10';
    }
  }
```